# I would like to change in JavaFX directory chooser to recognize project folders

Tags: javafx

When opening project selection dialog in Netbeans, project directories are recognized and marked with a different icons as shown on the image.

[image: Netbeans Open Project]

is it possible to have something similar with DirectoryChooser in JavaFX or I have to build it from scratch?

The only known until now is that a project folder will contains '.mdf' files.

Thank you for any ideas or suggestions.

Comment: I don't think this is possible; the `FileChooser` and `DirectoryChooser` hook into the platform native file and directory choosers. From the [documentation](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.graphics/javafx/stage/DirectoryChooser.html): *"These dialogs have look and feel of the platform UI components which is independent of JavaFX."*

Comment: Thank you James _D I have come to the same conclusion. The made them to have the same look and feel.